# Use git-hooks for certain branches (With Husky and git-branch-is)

Tags: git, npm, git-branch, package.json, husky

I use [husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) and [git-branch-is](https://github.com/kevinoid/git-branch-is) for git hooks. Below my package.json

```
{
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
     ...
},
"husky": {
  "hooks": {
    "pre-commit": "git-branch-is master && npm test",
    "pre-push": "git-branch-is master && npm test"
 }
}
```

With this options on commit from branch **feature/802** I resieve following error

```
Error: Current branch is "feature/802", not "master".
```

**Question**

1. How I can disable git hooks for branches which started with *"feature"*
2. Apply hooks only for *master* and *develop* branches.
3. Can be this realized without using bash scripts?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me. `git-branch-is` isn't necessary.

```
{
  "hooks": {
    "commit-msg": "if [[ $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) = develop ]]; then commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS; fi"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `if [ git-branch-is master]; then npm test; fi`. Then, the test `git-branch-is master` returning a failing (nonzero) exit value will not be treated as the hook's terminal failure.

This may raise issues if the hook needs to run outside of a POSIX-compliant shell.

Answer (score 0):

I check if branch is not master or branch is master and tests are successfull.

```
"pre-push": "git-branch-is -r \"^((?!master).)*$\" || (git-branch-is master && npm test)"
```

Comment: This seems like it might ne a good answer, but without explaining what part of your solution solves which problem, it's hard to assess. Please add some text to explain how your solution works.